# What are Story Impressions on Facebook apps?

Tags: facebook-apps

I have an app that says: 157,116 Story Impressions. I am wondering if this is how many times it was displayed on a Facebook page. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

[This Facebook KB article](https://www.facebook.com/help/274400362581037) shows what a Story Impression is (emphasis mine):

> Impressions are **the number of times a post from your Page is displayed**, whether the post is clicked or not. People may see multiple impressions of the same post. For example, someone might see a Page update in News Feed once, and then a second time if their friend shares it.